# Adding data to tables with Foreign key in Django

Tags: python, django-models, django-forms

I have two models

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    pono=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    podate=models.DateField()
    vendor=models.ForeignKey(Vendor,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    remarks=models.TextField()


class PurchaseOrder_Detail(models.Model):
    purchaseorder=models.ForeignKey(PurchaseOrder,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)        
    poqty=models.FloatField()
    rate=models.FloatField()
    cancleqty=models.FloatField(default=0)
    pending_qty=models.FloatField(default=0)
```

I am trying to add data in purchaseorder and PurchaseOrderdetail table. There is no problem in PurchaseOrder as there is no foreign key. But I am not able to insert data into PurchaseOrderDetail.
Can any one tell how to add data into purchaseorderDetail. User will not be able to enter data for purchaseorder_detail.purchaseorder_id, it will be auto selected in form's hidden field.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear. You can create object from `PurchaseOrder_Detail` simply by calling `.objects.create(**kwargs)` on it. If you need to pass value for foreign key fields, you should first get its object using `.objects.get(**kwargs)` or by slicing it from queryset of this related model.

Example:

```
    PurchaseOrder_Detail.objects.create(
            porchaseorder=PurchaseOrder.objects.get(id=5), 
            ...
    )
```

You can also point directly to id: `porchaseorder_id=5` in relational fields.

Comment: Here is the link to my github page https://github.com/k-quartz/store_mgmt.git

Comment: Where should I check? @Akash